# How to create a video preview in android?

Tags: android, android-image, android-imageview, android-video-player

I have a video file in my sdcard. I would like to show a preview of this video in my ImageView . Please let me know how to do this in Android. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Have you tried using the thumbnail utils

Answer (score 45):

If you use API level 8 and above. You can create preview of a video like this:

```
String videoFile = "/sdcard/blonde.mp4";
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFile,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Now you can show it in an `ImageView`:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

Or you can set it to a `VideoView` as a background, so that it is shown as a first video frame before the video starts playing:

```
VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.my_video_view);
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(thumbnail);
video.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

Comment: How does Samsung and others make short video previews that play as you view many videos?

Comment: FOR VIDEO TO PLAY FROM URL

Answer (score 1):

This example works for *blonde.mp4* file:

```
String videoFile = "/sdcard/blonde.mp4";
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFile, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```