# How to create a video preview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm currently working on a project where I get the following object:

```kotlin
data class VideosDetails(val id: String,
                         val title: String,
                         val thumbSmall: String,
                         val thumbPreview: String,
                         val duration: String)
```

I receive it in a form of a list, that I pass to my `RecyclerView`. To display my `thumbSmall` which is an image I use `Glide` and it's working well. I'd like to make a video preview using the `thumbPreview` which is a **`mp4`** so I can't use `Glide` for this.

I've read that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037630/how-to-create-a-video-preview-in-android) but it no longer works as `createVideoThumbnail` is deprecated. The doc says to use `ContentResolver.loadThumbnail(Uri, Size, CancellationSignal)` but I can't use it because the object `Size` is 21+ and my min Sdk is 19.

Should I just use `MediaPlayer` or `Exoplayer` to do this ? My concern about using this method is that since it'll be in a `RecyclerView` it'll take a lot of resources. Any advice are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I made a custom `recyclerview` that use one `Exoplayer` across its items and moves it along which item is clicked.

I made a repo if anyone wants to see how I did it, so here is the [repo](https://github.com/yoobi/exoplayer-kotlin/tree/feature/rvItemPreview) or here for the [custom recyclerview](https://github.com/yoobi/exoplayer-kotlin/blob/feature/rvItemPreview/app/src/main/java/com/app/exoplayer_kotlin/ExoplayerRecyclerView.kt)